# connection between Matlab and MySql

Tags: mysql, matlab

I am working on the project for matching images. For that purpose I have maintained image database (MySQL database) and image processing part done through the Matlab.

Hence I need a connection between those two software platform. Which is the best way to achieving this requirement??

Comment: There appears to be some [pretty good documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/database/ug/mysql-jdbc-windows.html) on the MathWorks website.  Have you given that a try?  If you have _and_ you still have problems, then come back here with a more focused question.

Comment: Thank you very much for your contribution on my request and it has work correctly.